# Android Studio: developing common java libraries to be shared among apps

Tags: java, android, libraries

I have been researching through SO and seen much discussion about linking an app to a library, but in all cases (that I have found) the libraries are imported into the app.

As I understand it, importing copies the library into the App.  In our case, we have several common java source libraries (L1, L2, etc) that are under active development and we want several Apps (A1, A2, etc) to reference these libraries.  This means the libraries cannot be imported/copied to the Apps, since the libraries are changing too often.

The libraries have been created as separate Android Projects (we tried creating a Module/Android Library, but that was no better).  We are using Android Studio for our IDE.

How do I go about linking without copying the libraries into a project?
Thanks.

Comment: So how do others handle library development for apps?  We are currently experimenting with generating a .jar file from each library and then importing each into each app.  This puts a local copy of each library file into each app project directory.  The problem is that each time the library is recompiled, the .jar file needs to be reimported to each app project.  Painful!

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE**: I have a much better [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49875199/8958408) now. I created a new Question for it (clarifying the actual issue) as this one has been marked as duplicate.

---

1. Place all libraries in a common folder (e.g. `~/AppProjects/lib/`).
2. Place a soft link to the lib folder into the app folders (`ln -s ~/AppProjects/lib/ ~/AppProjects/<app>/`).
3. When you call `File > New > New Module > Import Gradle Project`, you can then browse into the `lib` folder now in the `<app>` folder.

The library module will be imported in the standard way. But no copy will be made as it already "is" in the app folder; and changes will be saved directly in the library folder.

Caveat: after a change to a library file, a full build has to be done (`Build > Rebuild Project`), as `Make Project` yields the `compileDebugJavaWithJavac - Unable to find source java class` error.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [jitpack.io](https://jitpack.io/) to publish libraries and then use them the same way you'd use any other library on graddle, including versioning by git tags.

Basically, all you need is a git powered repository, such as Github, Bitbucket, GitLab etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [git submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) or [mercurial suberporitory](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Subrepository) to achieve this.
All module (app and library) has its own repository. 
From your app project you have one dedicated folder which contains external dependencies from other repositories. Then add the java library as sub-repository of your application.
The project layout will look something like this.

[image]

In `settings.gradle` of `MyApplication` project you have to include the `java-library`

```
include  ':java-library'
project(':java-library').projectDir = new File("external/java-library/")
include ':app'
```

and app's dependency `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(":java-library")
}
```