# Automating synchronization when developping several libraries and projects at the same time

Tags: java, android, version-control, repository, static-libraries

I want incremental updates of my library files to immediately be applied in all of my projects using them, without having to perform an extra step every time for every one of my projects (such as updating a sub-repository or a JAR file).

Comment: I am not concerned about source control issues. The incremental updates usually do not change interfaces, and if there is a change in interface which breaks compilation in other projects, I can either quickly fix the issue, or check out a version of the library files from around when I committed last, branch off from there, and merge later on when I have the time.

Comment: The solutions on [IntelliJ gradle add module dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38877989/intellij-gradle-add-module-dependency) and elsewhere don't do it for me, as they involve a step that has to be performed manually for each project ‏‏‎ - 
unless I missed something, if so please correct me!

Answer (score 0):

With the library folder in the `LIBS_DIR` environment variable:

```
// settings.gradle
include ':app', ':lib1', ':lib2'
project(':lib1').projectDir = new File(System.getenv('LIBS_DIR'), 'lib1')
project(':lib2').projectDir = new File(System.getenv('LIBS_DIR'), 'lib2')
```

‏‏‎

```
// build.gradle
...
dependencies {
    compile project(path: ':lib1')
    compile project(path: ':lib2')
}
```